# XSL fo block overflow continue in different block

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Lets asume I have a page that contains two main blocks of text. One in the upper half, one in the lower half of the page.
The upper block contains static data, the lower one contains dynamic data displayed as a "bullet-list"

The challenge now is - if the number of items of the bullet list exceeds the maximum available space for the lower block - i want the page to be "duplicated" and the listing continued on the second page, but also in the lower block. (The upper block should contain the same data as on the first page)

Even more perfect would be, if in case the list exceeds the space, the second page is created and filled as described, but also the last bulletpoint says "continued on next page" and the first one on the second page says "continued from last page".

Is that possible with xsl-t / xsl-fo? How to achive that?

Thanks alot in advance, Heiko

Answer (score 0):

If the upper half is always the same and has a known height, you could put the content in an `fo:static-content` that you would direct to a suitably sized `fo:region-before`.  You could then put the list content in the `fo:flow` so that it ends up in the `fo:region-body` region.

You could probably do the "continued on next page" and "continued from last page" using markers (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker).  Is the text supposed to take up some of the space for the list or is it meant to appear below/above the area for the list?

If the height of your upper half of static data isn't fixed, then you might need to put everything into an `fo:table` with the static data in the `fo:table-header`.

Comment: Thanks for the Ideas. I tried your attempt to put parts of the paper in a fo:static content - but unfortuately the upper part also contains dynamic content from the source-xml. And with that - apache-fop throws an error for using <apply-templates> in an static-content area.

Comment: It's a two-step process: you transform your source XML into the XSL-FO vocabulary using an XSLT processor then format that using as XSL formatter such as FOP or Antenna House.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e147.  The `<xsl:apply-templates>` makes sense to the XSLT processor, but not to the XSL formatter, as you've found out.  The XSLT transformation can happen inside the XSL formatter application if you feed it the right arguments, or it can be done using a standalone XSLT processor and you feed the XSL-FO to the XSL formatter using a different set of arguments.

Comment: So, if I get you right, you suggest to first create an xsl-fo file containing the data that is the same on each page, and lateron transform that same file again using different stylesheets to create the content that is different on each page?

So calling XSLT on an already TRANSFORMED File works?

Comment: Or maybe I explained it not clearly enough. Lets asume you have a listing of crimes some person commited and that list needs to be printed. On the upperhalf of the paper you have things like "Name, Birthdate" and so on. at the lower half, there is a listing of all the crimes.

So if the number of crimes is way too much to fit on one page - a second page shall be created with the upper half containing the same data as on the first page (Name, Birthdate...) but the listing of crimes is continued in the lower half.

Comment: Sorry, the two steps are 'your XML to XSL-FO' then 'XSL-FO to formatted output'.  That's just the one XSLT transformation.  I'm proposing that you produce '`<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before"><!-- FOs from static data --></fo:static-content><fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"><!-- FOs from dynamic data --></fo:flow>`'.  You'd make the `fo:region-before/@extent` large enough for the region to fit the static data and, more importantly, make the `fo:region-body/@margin-top` large enough that the body region doesn't overlap the before region (which maybe overflowed its extent).